# Raspberry pi web server from internet

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, noip

I have been trying to make an access to my Apache server on Raspberry Pi from internet for several days.

1. I set up Apache, PHP, mySQL, myadmin and put index.php to 'www' folder
2. I edited dhcpcd.conf to set static IP.

   ```
   interface eth0
   static ip_address=192.168.1.220/24
   static routers=192.168.1.1
   static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1
   ```
3. I registered mydomainname.net on no-ip.net for my internal IP address
4. Installed No-IP Dynamic Update Client on raspberry pi and it's status is active
5. I opened port 80 on my router for static IP Address of my RASPBERRY (192.168.1.220)
6. On my router I added my no-ip account and it shows status 'Success'
7. I even tried to change Apache listened port from 80 to 8090

But, whatever I do, I can't get access to mydomainname.net from internet, but I can do it from my local network on my static Raspberry IP - 192.168.1.220.

Comment: Not really a programming question. Try asking at [raspberrypi.se] or maybe [unix.se], or perhaps [sf].

Comment: Do a ping of mydomain.com and make sure it resolves to the correct IP (your public address), if it does, make sure you try and access it from OUTSIDE of your network. Many home routers won't port forward back in from their own LAN.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is the IP you are using is your internal IP. This IP is inaccessible from the outside. As long as you are inside your network you can use the internal IP adress tho.

try using https://www.canyouseeme.org/ to obtain your router IP adress maybe then you'll be able to acces it trough IP already. also this is the IP that you need to register on the host of your site.